# Pandas writing to CSV

Tags: python, string, pandas, unicode, export-to-csv

I am converting Pyspark dataframe to Pandas dataframe (python 3) and writing to csv. I am facing this issue while writing to csv after converting to Pandas()-

"TypeError: write() argument 1 must be unicode, not str"

I am facing this issue even while writing numerical columns. I have tried typecasting to str as well as Unicode. Also tried giving **encoding='utf-8'** as a parameter while writing csv. I always get the same error as mentioned above.

Would be grateful if someone can provide insight into debugging this.

Comment: It's a bit suspicious if you get a message about unicode/str when running Python 3, since the `unicode` type existed only in Python 2. Can you verify that you are really running Python 3?

Comment: Also, you should probably show a minimal code example, otherwise it's pretty pointless for us to guess where the wrong type gets passed around.